# Want to display an alert when the app enters foreground from background

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to build an iOS app, where when the app enters background and the user brings it to foreground, I want to display a message like "Welcome Back", Is there a way of doing that?
I have read about the UILocalNotification but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. For such kind of methods you should always look in AppDelegate.m file.
It has the default method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome back!" message:@"Welcome back!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Some of that kind...

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground:` method. This is called when the app returns to the foreground.